# No Such Cookbook error

Tags: chef-infra

I'm new to chef and trying to run through one of their "learn chef" modules...
https://learn.chef.io/modules/local-development/windows/virtualbox/apply-a-cookbook#/

I'm able to create the kitchen, but when I try to converge I get an error that the cookbook isn't found...
https://www.screencast.com/t/eucThbF6

I've tried this both with the "learn_chef_iis" cookbook they have you download from git, and from my own "my_iis" cookbook I made from scratch using the 'chef generate cookbook' command.

Both have the same error when I run converge about "No such cookbook".

If I run a "knife cookbook list", it lists both "learn_chef_iis" and "my_iis" as available cookbooks.

What am I missing here?

Error...

```
I, [2017-10-17T12:04:19.141823 #16224] INFO – default-windows-2012R2:
I, [2017-10-17T12:04:19.158336 #16224] INFO – default-windows-2012R2: ================================================================================
I, [2017-10-17T12:04:19.179353 #16224] INFO – default-windows-2012R2: Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
I, [2017-10-17T12:04:19.196367 #16224] INFO – default-windows-2012R2: ================================================================================
I, [2017-10-17T12:04:19.217884 #16224] INFO – default-windows-2012R2:
I, [2017-10-17T12:04:19.233897 #16224] INFO – default-windows-2012R2: Missing Cookbooks:
I, [2017-10-17T12:04:19.252912 #16224] INFO – default-windows-2012R2: ------------------
I, [2017-10-17T12:04:19.268925 #16224] INFO – default-windows-2012R2: No such cookbook: learn_chef_iis
I, [2017-10-17T12:04:19.315462 #16224] INFO – default-windows-2012R2:
I, [2017-10-17T12:04:19.332475 #16224] INFO – default-windows-2012R2: Expanded Run List:
I, [2017-10-17T12:04:19.349489 #16224] INFO – default-windows-2012R2: ------------------
I, [2017-10-17T12:04:19.366503 #16224] INFO – default-windows-2012R2: * learn_chef_iis::default
I, [2017-10-17T12:04:19.384017 #16224] INFO – default-windows-2012R2:
I, [2017-10-17T12:04:19.401531 #16224] INFO – default-windows-2012R2: System Info:
I, [2017-10-17T12:04:19.419045 #16224] INFO – default-windows-2012R2: ------------
I, [2017-10-17T12:04:19.435558 #16224] INFO – default-windows-2012R2: chef_version=13.5.3
I, [2017-10-17T12:04:19.452571 #16224] INFO – default-windows-2012R2: platform=windows
I, [2017-10-17T12:04:19.469585 #16224] INFO – default-windows-2012R2: platform_version=6.3.9600
I, [2017-10-17T12:04:19.486599 #16224] INFO – default-windows-2012R2: ruby=ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x64-mingw32]
```

Full transcript of the log files (long) can be seen here...
https://discourse.chef.io/t/chef-cookbook-not-found/11757/3

Metadata.rb:

```
name 'my_iis'
maintainer 'The Authors'
maintainer_email 'you@example.com'
license 'All Rights Reserved'
description 'Installs/Configures my_iis'
long_description 'Installs/Configures my_iis'
version '0.1.0'
chef_version '>= 12.1' if respond_to?(:chef_version)
```

Berksfile:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

metadata
```

Kitchen.yml

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant
  boot_timeout: 1200
  gui: true

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero

verifier:
  name: inspec

transport:
  name: winrm
  elevated: true
  username: Administrator
  password: Pass@word1

platforms:
  - name: windows-2012R2
    driver:
      customize:
        memory: 2048

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[my_iis::default]
    verifier:
      inspec_tests:
        - test/smoke/default
    attributes:
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add the error message as text here.

Comment: Add your metadata.rb, Berksfile etc.

Comment: Updated with that info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing a reference to learn_chef_iis in your metadata, which berkflow uses to compile the lock file and download dependencies. Try the following:

1. delete your berksfile.lock file in the root of your cookbook
2. Add the following line to the end of your metadata.rb file

   depends 'chef_learn_iis', '0.2.1'
3. Run again. Your berksfile.lock will be regenerated at the start of the run and the dependencies should be downloaded to your node for consumption.

All cookbooks that you depend on are downloaded to the chef cache location and used locally so you're likely seeing this error because chef_learn_iis is never actually downloaded.